# Yugabyte YCQL check if a set contain a value?

Tags: yugabytedb

Is there there any way to query on a SET type(or MAP/LIST) to find does it contain a value or not?

Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test.table_name(
    id text,
    ckk SET<INT>,
    PRIMARY KEY((id))
);

Select * FROM table_name WHERE id = 1 AND ckk CONTAINS 4;
```

Is there any way to reach this query with YCQL api?

And can we use a SET type in SECONDRY INDEX?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to reach this query with YCQL api?

YCQL does not support the `CONTAINS` keyword yet (feel free to open an issue for this on the [YugabyteDB GitHub](https://github.com/YugaByte/yugabyte-db/issues)). 
One workaround can be to use `MAP<INT, BOOLEAN>` instead of `SET<INT>` and the `[]` operator.
For instance:

```
CREATE TABLE test.table_name(
    id text,
    ckk MAP<int, boolean>,
    PRIMARY KEY((id))
);
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = 'foo' AND ckk[4] = true;
```

> And can we use a SET type in SECONDRY INDEX?

Generally, collection types cannot be part of the primary key, or an index key.
However, "frozen" collections (i.e. collections serialized into a single value internally) can actually be part of either primary key or index key.

For instance:

```
CREATE TABLE table2(
    id TEXT,
    ckk FROZEN<SET<INT>>,
    PRIMARY KEY((id))
) WITH transactions = {'enabled' : true};
CREATE INDEX table2_idx on table2(ckk);
```

Comment: it seems using `Map<int, boolean>` can solve my problem. but can i use Subscripted expression  on a frozen map?

Comment: @AliZeinali You can't use subscripted expression with a frozen map but you can with a normal map. Can you open an issue on github https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/issues ? Why do you need a frozen map ? To use it as a primary key ?

Comment: Lets say i have a table to store my posts and each post can have some tag (there is limit number of tags) then i want search for posts which contain some tags. This query most be fast so i need to create a secondary index on tags (by the same partition key  as post pk)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use with compound primary key and defining `ckk` as clustering key:

```
cqlsh> CREATE TABLE ybdemo.tt(id TEXT, ckk INT, PRIMARY KEY ((id), ckk)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (ckk DESC);
cqlsh> SELECT * FROM ybdemo.tt WHERE id='foo' AND ckk=4;
```

Comment: It's not what i'm looking for. ckk most be collection. And Repeating a row with different ckk would affect Write performance which i really don't want it :).

Comment: How many values do you intend to save in 1 collection column ?

Comment: Between 1 to 10

Comment: Are there other columns in the table ?

Comment: Yes, It's a table which store messages of an instance messaging app. So there is other columns probably with large data like JSONB, TEXT, BLOB and others

Comment: I suggest to create another table only with (pk,ckk) clustering column which can also be indexed and join the data in application side (on query time).
I don't think write-performance will be very different. It's all key-values underneath https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/architecture/docdb/persistence/#ycql-collection-type-example .

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that. I wounder how i haven't seen this page before.

Comment: If you want to make it more complex:: on the original table use a frozen<set>, selecting the whole set will be fine, and maintain a secondary index manually. On insert, also upsert the <cck,id> rows. The same with update+delete. This can work with transactions. This helps so you don't have to do application side join when selecting messages.